# Selecting fields based on FiscaL Year and Period

Tags: sql, oracle11g

The table I'm using has an amount field, a fiscal year, and a period field (among other fields).  I need to select the amount field twice based on the fiscal year and period fields.  The issue I'm having is how to write the SQL to select the record with fiscal year 2014 and period 10 for the prior amount.  I also need to make sure that it works for 2014 / 01 and the prior period is 2013 / 12.  Thanks for your help......

```
SELECT 
a.business_unit,
a.amount as CURRENT_AMOUNT,
a.amount as PRIOR_AMOUNT,
a.fiscal_year as FY,
a.period as AP

FROM Asset_Depreciation a

WHERE
a.business_unit = 'A0001'
AND a.fiscal_year = 2014
AND a.period = 11
```

RESULTS
A0001        500.00       (blank)             2014          11

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lag()` analytic function to find the previous `amount`.  You can use a subquery to apply `lag()` before the `where` filter:

```
select  prevamount
,       business_unit
,       curamount
,       fiscal_year
,       period
from    (
        select  lag(amount) over (
                    partition by business_unit
                    order by fiscal_year, period) as prevamount
        ,       business_unit
        ,       amount as curamount
        ,       fiscal_year
        ,       period
        from    Asset_Depreciation
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   business_unit = 'A0001'
        and fiscal_year = 2014
        and period = 11
```

Without the subquery, `lag()` will only look at one row and not find any previous value.

[Working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/451ff/3/0)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm new to writing sql and am not sure what would go into the subquery.  I looked at SQL Fiddle and see the 1 row in the results.  What I would like to see is the current amount and prior amount on the same row.  Is this possible?  I appreciate your help....

Comment: If you remove the `where` clause, it will return more rows.  The previous and current amount will be in the same row.

Comment: Thank You.  I've tried to modify the query you have shown me because I need to join to another table.  I tried to post it here but it's too long.  I'm going to create another question to see if anyone can tell me what is wrong with the sql.  Thanks again